# Removing rows of a matrix based on rows of another matrix

Tags: matlab, find

Imagine I have two matrices with different sizes (let's say 6x2 and 5x2) as follows:

```
A = [47 10;
29 10;
23 10;
34 10;
12 10;
64 10];

B = [23 20;
12 20;
54 20
47 20;
31 20];
```

I need to compare A(:,1) with B(:,1) and delete the rows in matrix A whose first-column-element is different from matrix B's first-column-element (so my focus is only on first columns of the matrices). So I should eventually get something like this:

```
A = [47 10;
12 10;
23 10];
```

as "47", "12", and "23" are the only first-column-elements in A that also exist in B! I have written this but I get the error "Matrix dimensions must agree."!

```
TF = A(:,1) ~= B(:,1);    %define indexes in A that A(:,1) is not equal to B(:,1)
A(TF,:) = [];
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
result = A(ismember(A(:,1), B(:,1)), :);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this line

```
TF = A(:,1) ~= B(:,1);
```

with this line

```
[~,TF] = setdiff(A(:,1),B(:,1));
```

yields the desired result.